# Why are backslashes in URIs automatically converted to forward slashes in FOP 2.7?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, apache-fop

I am trying to generate a PDF document from a basic XML file, which is styled by XSLT (v2.0). FOP 2.7 is being used to generate the PDF document, from the command line. One of the tags in the input XML contains a URL as an attribute, which is being placed as a clickable link in the output PDF document.

Simple example XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<testxmlroot>
<name>Test URL</name>
<a href ="https://example.com/someting/Default/GetSometing?path=\one\two\three%20four\five"/>
<desc>Example of the type of URL required.</desc>
</testxmlroot>
```

Simple xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:altova="http://www.altova.com" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="altova">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:param name="SV_OutputFormat" select="'PDF'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="fo:layout-master-set">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-master-0-even" margin-left="0.1in" margin-right="0.1in" page-height="8.3in" page-width="11.7in" margin-top="0.1in" margin-bottom="0.30in">
        <fo:region-body column-count="1"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="even-page-header" overflow="hidden"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-master-0-odd" margin-left="0.1in" margin-right="0.1in" page-height="8.3in" page-width="11.7in" margin-top="0.1in" margin-bottom="0.30in">
        <fo:region-body column-count="1"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="odd-page-header" overflow="hidden"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
      <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="page-master-0">
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
          <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page-master-0-even" odd-or-even="even"/>
          <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page-master-0-odd" odd-or-even="odd"/>
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
      </fo:page-sequence-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="altova:nPxPerIn" select="96"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$fo:layout-master-set"/>
      <fo:declarations>
        <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
          <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
              <xmp:CreatorTool>Altova StyleVision Enterprise Edition 2016 (http://www.altova.com)</xmp:CreatorTool>
            </rdf:Description>
          </rdf:RDF>
        </x:xmpmeta>
      </fo:declarations>
      <!--PDF Main Heading-->
      <fo:page-sequence force-page-count="no-force" master-reference="page-master-0" initial-page-number="1" format="1">
        MainHeading
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block>
          <xsl:for-each select ="//a">
          <xsl:if test ="@href">
            <fo:basic-link color ="blue" text-decoration ="underline" external-destination ="{@href}">
            <xsl:value-of select ="@href" disable-output-escaping ="yes"/>
            </fo:basic-link>
          </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Command line inputs:

```
./fop.bat -xml "E:\StackOverflow.xml" -xsl "E:\StackOverflow.xsl" -pdf E:\FOPExperimentation\outputfile.pdf -c E:\fop.xconf
```

The text printed in the rudimentary output PDF contains the slashes as present in the XML file, but upon selecting the link itself, or copy pasting the URL, we can see the slashes converted. In my use case, the URL is unusable without the backslashes.

Comment: Which tool do you use to display the PDF with the link and then to copy or follow the link?

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using Microsoft Edge to open the PDF and follow the link in the same. I've tried opening the document in Adobe Acrobat Reader, but the URL still has the slashes converted.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. However, in my use case, the URL corresponds to a sort of web service, where the portion after the '?path=' corresponds to a local path on a shared drive. Altering it is causing the web service to fail, causing issue.